# Ajax cache control

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, caching, header

I am having a problem with ajax requests in Internet Explorer and in Chrome - I cannot bust the cache.  Normal pages don't have the problem - it's just the ajax requests.

I know that one workaround is to append a random query string variable to the end of the URL.  However, I don't want to lose all the benefits of caching, I just want the browser to pick up the new file if the version on the server is different from the cached version.

I have tried manually setting the ajax POST header, to no avail:

> xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");

Adding this to my .htaccess file doesn't work either:

> `<FilesMatch "\.(js|css).*"`>
>   Header set Cache-Control: "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
>   `</FilesMatch`>

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating/extending a component that emits your css/js includes with the latest versions appended to the links? This way it's not going to grab a fresh copy *every* time, and will only grab a new version when the server says there is one.

Comment: That's actually a fantastic idea.  My only issue is that I'm using the mod_concat apache module which requires the <script> tag to be written in a way that is not compatible with query strings.  I'd like to continue using it, so a solution using the Headers would be ideal.  Thanks.

Comment: Solved the issue by using this answer in combination with mod_rewrite to get around the restrictions imposed by mod_concat.  Thanks for the help.